# Connection between Freiheitssatz and Magnus property

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I am currently studying the Magnus property:

> Let $G$ be a group and $u, v \in G$. If the normal closures
>   of $u$ and $v$ coincide, then $u$ is conjugate to $v$ or $v^{−1}$.

I was told that this property was named after W. Magnus who proved the [Freiheitsatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitssatz) and that free groups have this property in [this text in pages 141-165](https://eudml.org/doc/149736?fbclid=IwAR1W9cea5abxDbyLhpZfmzSESTZ-gBZIgEldUFYPjPwSVbzNJdUGby7xQ-8). However, this text is in German, which I am not fluent in, and is very technical, using multiple lemma's and notation that I am not familiar with.

I do have a decent understanding of group theory and was hoping that some body could give some intuitive way of seeing how the Freiheitsatz implies free groups having the Magnus property?

Comment: Please use a type of $\LaTeX$ called MathJax here in future. Tutorials are freely available online.

Answer (score 2):

The result you state about free groups is Theorem 4.11 of the standard text *Combinatorial group theory* by Magnus, Karrass and Solitar* (p261 of my copy). The book includes an English-language proof of this result, as well as a proof of the Freiheitssatz itself. The proof in the book is 4.5 pages long, and the idea is to apply "Magnus' method". This method was first used by Magnus to study one-relator groups, and indeed is the method used in the text you link too.

*However*, these proofs are painful. They use something called "staggered presentations", which was Magnus' original way of applying his method. A more up-to-date version of Magnus' method, due to Moldavanski, uses HNN-extensions**. You can find detailed descriptions of this method in the paper McCool, Schupp, *On one relator groups and HNN extensions*, J. Aust. Math. Soc. 16(02):249--256 (1973), and also in [these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/OneRelator.pdf) of Andy Putman. Neither resource contains a proof of the result that you are after, but I guess you can try to turn the handle if you are enthusiastic enough. Sounds like a nice master's project actually! :-)

---

I should say a few words about Magnus' method. Any proof which uses Magnus' method must apply the Freiheitssatz somewhere (in particular, the proof of Theorem 4.11 in Magnus, Karrass and Solitar - the proof that you are interested in - uses the Freiheitssatz, as you were told). Magnus' method is an inductive argument on the length of the word $R$. An explicit example of a single step in the HNN-version of the method is as follows: Suppose $R=ab^2c^2a^{-1}b^2c^2$ and consider the group $G=\langle a, b, c\mid R\rangle$. We have the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle a, b, c\mid ab^2c^2a^{-1}b^2c^2\rangle&\cong\langle a, b_0, c_0, b_1, c_1\mid ab_0^2c_0^2a^{-1}b_0^2c_0^2, ab_0a^{-1}=b_1, ac_0a^{-1}=c_1\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a, b_0, c_0, b_1, c_1\mid b_1^2c_1^2b_0^2c_0^2, ab_0a^{-1}=b_1, ac_0a^{-1}=c_1\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
By the Freiheitssatz, the subgroup $\langle b, c\rangle$ of $G$ is free of rank two. Hence, $\langle b_0, c_0\rangle$ and $\langle b_1, c_1\rangle$ are also free of rank two. Therefore, the above working shows that $G$ is an HNN-extension of the group $G_1=\langle b_0, c_0, b_1, c_1\mid b_1^2c_1^2b_0^2c_0^2\rangle$. This new group $G_1$ has a single defining relator which is shorter than the relator of the old group, so we have our induction step.

---

*This book is usually referred to as "Magnus, Karrass and Solitar" to distinguish it from "Lyndon and Schupp"; both sets of authors wrote books called "combinatorial group theory", and both books are still standard texts in geometric group theory.

**Jim Howie gave an alternative version of the method using "staggered complexes", while a third method used "pictures" (I cannot find out at the moment who first used this third method, but I know Hamish Short used it in his early work). All three methods are essentially equivalent, but HNN-extensions are much more standard in group theory and so the proofs are more readable to the generalist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a bit confused/worried that i may be on the wrong path here. I was under the impression that the Freiheitsatz was used to prove that free groups have the Magnus property, since most my sources about Magnus property mention both in the same sentence. Since neither of the sources you mention contain a proof of this format, do you think i misinterpretted my sources?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The Freiheitssatz *is* used to prove this result; in fact, any proof which uses Magnus' method applies the Freiheitssatz somewhere! So you are on the right path.

Comment: Hi! So after reading up on HNN-extensions and proofs of the Magnus theorem & method and working on that example you gave me i think i understand most of it, but there is just one thing i can't quite (rigorously) figure out about the proving of the induction step: I get that you can construct an isomorphism as in your example and then show that $G$ is an HNN-extension of some group with one-relator of a shorter length, hence on that group we can use the induction hypothesis. But how does this help us to prove that our subset of generators in $G$ generates a free subgroup?

Comment: Is this because of the embedding from $G_1$ to $G$?

Comment: Its difficult to work out your question. Did you find a proof written down? For example, see page 3 of the [McCool-Schupp paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-one-relator-groups-and-hnn-extensions/A51E086AF79B5D32E0F2A590B01BF779), which is open access. This explains why your subgroup is free.

Comment: Following page 250-251 of the McCool-Schupp paper you linked, I believe that your group $G_1$ should be infinitely generated. Carrying out your recipe as stated for $G$ a free group supposedly gives an isomorphism between $G$ and a non-free one-relator group.

Comment: @BenS Yes, in McCool-Schupp's paper they don't bound the indices so their group $G_1$ is infinitely generated, and Putman seems to do the same. However, usually we put a bound on the indices used, which gives a finitely generated group $G_1'$ say. The two groups are related by $G_1\cong G_1'\ast F$ for $F$ some (non-finitely generated) free group. (Using indices $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ is just quicker to write, with the bounds being $m\leq i\leq M$ where $m$ is the minimum exponent sum of your stable letter which is contained in your word, and $M$ being the maximum.)

Comment: I don't understand your point about showing there is an isomorphism between $G$ and a non-free one-relator group. Can you explain your working? (Or maybe ask it as a new question, linking back to this one? This would give you more space to explain the issue, etc.)

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. I was having trouble seeing the first isomorphism you wrote, but I got it now. The point is that, for example,

$\langle a,b,\mid \rangle\cong\langle a,b_0,b_1\mid ab_0a^{−1}=b_1 \rangle$ via $a\mapsto a,b_0\mapsto b, b_1\mapsto aba^{-1}$